# What is the best way to transport a large quantity of LEGO bricks?

Tags: storage, transport

I have a decently sized collection (thousands of bricks/hundreds of sets/a bunch of bins) from my childhood, but they're all at my parents' house. I live in the US and a couple states away from my parents (more than 1000 miles). What is the best way to package all of the bricks? What is the best way to move all of those packages? I ask because I'm thinking the weight of them all might make it tricky to transport. Hopefully someone out there has been in a similar situation.

Comment: You may want to contact experienced BrickLink or eBay sellers, since they routinely do that kind of thing.

Comment: Are there any of those on this site?

Comment: I have no idea, but I suppose if there are, they will answer...

Answer (score 5):

When I moved house, I just sealed the gaps in a bunch of packing boxes with duct/packing tape, and put the storage bins in there - that way if anything did escape from the bins it wasn't going to get lost from the box.

I would say though that in general my collection wasn't organised in anyway, although there were a few built sets that survived fairly well.

Answer (score 1):

No personal experience, but one vendor I've seen a couple years now at Brick Fiesta just ships boxes full, roughly U-Haul medium sized. He has some cardboard 'trays', but I'm pretty sure they are not structurally useful. He also had stuff bagged up into various types and some level of sorting, but that's not really important to shipping either.

Of course, if you have some relatively delicate bits (like [part:2337:46]), take care to pack them with as little stress on them as possible.

(ok, clearly I'm not getting how to do part linking)

Answer (score -1):

Pack them in a box and surround them with things that are soft.