# Selling bulk LEGO

Tags: shopping, star-wars, transport

I have most Star Wars sets, plus the complete Enterprise.  They have been taken apart and I do not have all instructions.  What is the best suggestion to sell?  I also have the Death Star dismantled.  I do have at least 6 Star Wars ships that are intact.  If I sell those, how do I get them to the buyer?

Comment: Most of the instructions are available online.  They will generally sell for more as buildable sets than random bricks.  Selling as sets would generally not be considered selling LEGO in bulk.

Comment: For bulk selling, see: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/9716/56, for transportation options see: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1914/56 or the [tag:transport] tag.

Answer (score 3):

An Enterprise has never been an official LEGO set. Lego does not have the licenses to produce Star Trek sets. Some clone brands have offered it, so I conclude that clone or custom  LEGO is mixed into your bulk. You should filter the non-LEGO out of your bulk if you wish to sell it as  LEGO.

Comment: The Enterprise reference made me wonder as well.  I assumed they were talking about the Millennium Falcon, but non-LEGO is a good guess as well.  Hopefully Sheila will return and let us know the real story.